# How to sort on GroupingSummary instead of child records

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I cant seem to figure out how to sort groupsummary info.

notice here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/44o when u hit sort it only sorts the child rows not the group summary information

does anybody know how to sort on the summary itself ?

i have tried sorterFn and tried creating my own sorter, but still no go

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: sadly yes, i was unable to come up with a solution

Comment: `groupingsummary` doesn't support sorting by group titles. This is by design I think to prevent confusion with the default sort behavior.

Comment: im unsure how more ppl dont complain for not having this feature. i have so much data that its almost impossible to use because of the lack of grouping